# Sufficient conditions for a continuous function to have a positive (negative) third derivative? Fourth derivative?

Tags: calculus, functions

Assuming $f$ is single/double/triple/etc... differentiable, we know that if $f$ is increasing, then it has a positive first derivative and if $f$ is convex then it has a positive second derivative. What are the analogous characteristics of $f$ that guarantee it has a positive third/fourth/etc... derivative?

Comment: The first and second derivatives have obvious impacts on the original function. But as the derivatives get higher, their impacts become far more subtle. The third indicates if the curvature of the function is increasing or decreasing. By the time you get to the fourth derivative, there is little to distinguish its impact visually.

Comment: @PaulSinclair What is the algebraic way to capture the increasing/decreasing nature of curvature of a function?

Comment: "Curvature" is a geometric property, and a differential property, not an algebraic property. Geometrically, you best-fit a circle tangent to the curve at a given point on it. the curvature is the inverse of the radius of that best-fit circle. But the curvature in my previous comment is signed. If the circle is below the curve, it is positive, if the circle is above the curve it is negative (or vice versa - I'm not up to checking which right now). For the differential version, look up the Frenet equations.